# Name a stage per build-arguments using a Dockerfile with multi-stage-builds

Tags: dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

Is there a possibiliity to name a build-stage?
I am searching something like the following example:

```
ARG NAME

FROM python:3.7-alpine as modul-${NAME}
# ...
```

If I try this example this error occurs:

```
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 5: invalid name for build stage: "modul-${NAME}", name can't start with a number or contain symbols
```

I also tryed to use the argument as tag (`modul:${NAME}`) with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with BuildKit, which requires docker 18.09+. (https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/)

All you have to do is set an env variable before building:

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t whatever .`

I don't think it's possible without BuildKit.

Comment: I was using Docker version 20.10.21 and this didn't seem to work.

Comment: This doesn't work: this answer should not be voted as the accepted one.